# Transferring repo from bitbucket to github failing

Tags: git, ubuntu, github, ssh, bitbucket

I am trying to import a repository into github from my bitbucket account it seems to be failing and shows following message,

```
"Your old project requires credentials for read-only access
We will only temporarly store them for importing."
```

Path used for importing looked something like: https://blahb@bitbucket.org/blal/blahblahblah.git

What credentials should I put in and where should I put the credentials? I am trying the "Import Repository" feature of github given on their website: [image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
Your old project requires credentials for read-only access
We will only temporarly store them for importing.
```

This basically means that we need to give the BitBucket login ID and password. When I entered BitBucket ID and password, importing went through fine and I could then see the imported repo on github.

Comment: I've tried both Bitbucket and Github credentials & I'm still getting the same warning. Could it be because the repo is private on Bitbucket?

Comment: @SamYoungNY, I am not sure but I am afraid a private repo may not be allowed to be transferred.

Comment: @SamYoungNY it works for private repositories as well see my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47339212/1528427

Comment: Make a read only app password here...
https://bitbucket.org/account/settings/app-passwords/

Answer (score 16):

Use your Bitbucket credentials.

**Note:** if you have enabled two-factor authentication on Bitbucket. Go to Bitbucket settings and create app password. Use that generated password when you are authentication on GitHub instead of your normal Bitbucket password.

It also work for private repositories.

Comment: This worked for me, also don't use your EMAIL, use your username in combination with the app password

Answer (score 5):

For anyone else having this issue, my problem was that I was entering my email address in the `username input`. Your `username` is actually not your email and can be found in `Personal Settings / Bitbucket profile settings` on the Bitbucket website.

TDLR. Use username not email

Answer (score 3):

folks if you are having the same problem as mine I fixed this by providing repo owner/maintainer username and then in the password field i have  entered my `personal-access-token` as I had personal access token on my github repos.

Check out personal access token docs [here](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token)

The answer is described in more details bellow

https://github.community/t/import-repository-not-working/2044/2

Answer (score 0):

Use your Bitbucket ID and Password and not Github's credentials. It may seem confusing, because your browser may be populating GitHub's credentials since you are on Github's site.

Answer (score 0):

I got kept on getting that dialog when I provided my GitHub credentials.
You need to provide BitBucket credentials.

Answer (score 0):

If you are requested to enter a login and a token, you can simply create the access token in the repository settings in Bitbucket. For the login, you have to use "**x-token-auth**" instead of your credentials.